# Why doesn't my fan work unless plugged into GFCI standard outlet or surge protector?

Tags: electrical

A fan plugged into a GFCI works fine. The same fan does not work when plugged into a two pronged outlet. This fan will work when plugged into a surge protector that is plugged into the same two pronged outlet.

Where is my problem?

Comment: It could be the outlet or the fan. If the prongs on the fan are slightly bent the 2 prong may be worn enough that it is not making contact. Is the 2 prong polarized? 1 hole taller than the other? If its not polarized it is an antique and needs to at least be updated to a polarized outlet and that will probably solve the problem even if the prongs are bent on the fan.

Comment: Can you take a photo of the fan plug? curious the condition of the fan. @Ed Beal, the polarization shouldn't make a difference (right or wrong) even if its not to current code - (right or wrong)  :D

Comment: Older non polarized outlets didnot have the same amount of contact area. And at this age it may be opened up internally its not about the polarization itself.

Answer (score 1):

What your are saying is that you have a broken neutral and its shorting across the ground. That's why it won't work unless you have a path through the ground prong. This is potentially a dangerous situation. So get rid of the fan or have it repaired, but whatever you decide. **Don't use this fan in this condition.**

Comment: i don't follow this. The fan has a two prong plug presumably, unless we assume the OP left off a critical detail as to how he plugged it to a two prong outlet.